#  Multiples Object Relationship in Code First

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following Entities:

- Customers
- Companies
- Employees
- Orders
- Order-Elements

Then I have another entity called Notes. Each entity can have many Notes, how you accomplish this with code first fluent API? The goal is to have an object Id on the Notes tables and this entity id would point to the proper entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework does not support heterogeneous associations out of the box (other frameworks, like NHibernate, do)

My workaround is to use a `NoteService` that stores and retrieves the notes for a persistent entity.

Here's a simplified excerpt:

```
public ICollection<Note> GetNotes(IEntity entity)
{
    var entityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType()).Name;
    return context.Query<Note>()
                  .Where(x => x.EntityId == entity.Id &&
                              x.EntityType == entityType)
                  .ToList();
}

public void AddNote(IEntity entity, Note note)
{
    note.EntityType = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType()).Name;
    note.EntityId = entity.Id;
    context.Add(note);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend every entities with new base class that map Notes property (es. WithComment) 
and than you can write a class to map the new property:

```
public class WithComment
{
   public virtual IList<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : WithComment
{
}

public class CustomerMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
      public CustomerMapping ()
      {
          ToTable( "Customers" );
          ..........................

          HasMany<Notes>( o => o.Notes); // relation to note class
      }
}
```

and then add configuration

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
      public MyContext() { }

      protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
      {
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add( new CustomerMapping() );

          base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
      }
 }
```